# Is g++ 4.5.3 broken when it comes to pointers to lamba functions?

Tags: g++, lambda

I was trying out lambda functions and making a jump table to execute them, but I found g++ didn't recognize the type of the lambda function such that I could assign them to an array or tuple container.

One such attempt was this:

```
auto x = [](){};
decltype(x) fn = [](){};
decltype(x) jmpTable[] = { [](){}, [](){} };
```

On compilation I get these errors:

```
tst.cpp:53:27: error: conversion from ‘main()::<lambda()>’ to non-scalar type ‘main()::<lambda()>’ requested
tst.cpp:54:39: error: conversion from ‘main()::<lambda()>’ to non-scalar type ‘main()::<lambda()>’ requested
```

Hmmmm, can't convert from type A to *non-scalar* type A? What's that mean? o.O

I can use std::function to get this to work, but a problem with that is it doesn't seem to work with tuple:

```
function<void()> jmpTable[] = [](){}; // works
struct { int i; function<void()>> fn; } myTuple = {1, [](){}}; // works
tuple<int, function<void()>> stdTuple1 = {1, [](){}}; // fails
tuple<int, function<void()>> stdTuple2 = make_tuple(1, [](){}); // works
```

```
tst.cpp:43:58: error: converting to ‘std::tuple<int, std::function<void()> >’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::tuple(_U1&&, _U2&&) [with _U1 = int, _U2 = main()::<lambda()>, _T1 = int, _T2 = std::function<void()>]’
```

Constructor marked explicit? Why?

So my question is if I am doing something invalid or is this version just not quite up to the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hmmmm, can't convert from type A to non-scalar type A? What's that mean? o.O

No, that's not a conversion to the same type. Despite having identical bodies, the different lambdas have different types. Newer versions of GCC make this clearer, and give the error message:

```
error: conversion from '__lambda1' to non-scalar type '__lambda0' requested
```

clang does even better:

```
error: no viable conversion from '<lambda at test.cc:2:18>' to 'decltype(x)' (aka '<lambda at test.cc:1:10>')
```

> I can use std::function to get this to work, but a problem with that is it doesn't seem to work with tuple:

It does (with 4.5.4, at least, I don't have 4.5.3 to test), but your initialisation isn't quite right.

```
tuple<int, function<void()>> stdTuple1 {1, [](){}}; // lose the = to initialise stdTuple1 directly
```

Comment: So they are different types because they are different lambdas?  It's not looking at the lambda's signature?  Why would that be?  And the 2nd answer of removing the `=` would suggest to me that the operator=() is not overloaded properly.

Comment: @Adrian Lambdas, generally speaking, need to be implemented using special compiler-generated types that can hold references to any objects captured by the lambda. That special type then provides an `operator()` so that the lambda is callable. Since the implementation of `operator()` in each lambda is different, it makes sense for the lambda types themselves to be different.

Comment: @Adrian As for `operator=`, `T a = ...;` is initialisation, not assignment. `T a = { b, c };` (when `T` has a constructor accepting `b` and `c`) implicitly creates a temporary object, and initialises `a` using that temporary object. The temporary object *may* be omitted by the compiler, but the required checks do have to be performed. Since the constructor is `explicit`, and the creation of the temporary is implicit, it's not allowed. Without the `=`, `stdTuple1` is initialised directly and explicitly, and the explicit constructor can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the state of [n3043](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3043.html) in 4.5.3, but you should be able to use function pointer conversion. If I'm not misunderstanding your usage intentions, this may work for you;

```
void (*x)();
decltype(x) fn = [](){};
decltype(x) jmpTable[] = { [](){}, [](){} };
```

Comment: This assumes the lambdas have no capture lists, though. The test lambdas in the question might not, but there is no telling what the real lambdas contain.